# VSTS Load Testing as part of CD pipeline

Tags: load-testing, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As part of Release pipeline, created a cloud load test TASK.
What should be the path given under Load Test files folder?
On deployment, it gives me an error:

> ERR -> The path for the load test files
>   D:\a\r1\a\SourceCI\drop\LoadTestproject\bin\Release does not exist.
>   Please provide a valid path.

Comment: Did you enter the load test file name in the task settings? Can you share a screenshot for the settings?

Comment: Link for task settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCNKN.png                                    Link for folder structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AdeC.png

Comment: Which artifact did you choose when configure the release pipeline? Build Artifact or Git?

Comment: Build artificat

Comment: Is the LoadTest1.loadtest file published to build artifact during the build? And if yes, did you check the relative path in the drop?

Comment: Thanks Eddie Chen for pointing out on the release pipeline config, once I configured on GIT release pipeline the issue got resolved.

Comment: Glad to here that, I added the solution as answer. Feel free to mark it. :)

Comment: @Soujanya, Since this issue has been resolved, if possible, you could mark the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow. So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicated that the loadtest file cannot be found. You need to make sure that the loadtest file is published to build artifact and downloaded during the release if your release use the build artifact. Or you can configure your release definition to use Git artifact directly.